# Mysql одним запросом выбрать из нескольких НЕ связанных таблиц

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

На всех страницах знаю точно будут отображаться контакты и категории, они **не связаны друг с другом и имеют разные имена столбцов**, как из базы данных вытянуть одним запросом эти данные? Можно конечно два запроса, но может можно обойтись одним?
Если делаю так, то работает, но все поля с обеих таблиц с названиями из таблицы Contacts

```
$res = $this->pdo->query('SELECT * FROM Contacts UNION ALL SELECT * FROM categories');
return $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

На выходе:

```
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [icon] => Иконка
                    [label] => Название оператора 1
                    [value] => 7865435
                    [sort] => 1
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [icon] => Иконка 2
                    [label] => Название оператора 2
                    [value] => 676879789789
                    [sort] => 2
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [icon] => 
                    [label] => Категория 1
                    [value] => cat_slug_1
                    [sort] => 1
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [icon] => 
                    [label] => Категория 2
                    [value] => cat_slug_2
                    [sort] => 2
                )
```

По идее думал сделать так

```
$res = $this->pdo->query('SELECT * as contacts FROM Contacts UNION ALL SELECT * as categories FROM categories');
        return $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

но выдает ошибку: **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean**, добавлял кавычки, но не помогает.

Как сделать чтобы в итоге получить всё одним запросом с разделением на contacts и categories и у каждого результата имена своих столбцов? Тоесть нужно получить:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [contacts] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [icon] => Иконка
                    [label] => Название оператора 1
                    [value] => 7865435
                    [sort] => 1
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [icon] => Иконка 2
                    [label] => Название оператора 2
                    [value] => 676879789789
                    [sort] => 2
                )


        )
    [categories] => Array 
        (
        [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [title] => Категория 1
                    [slug] => cat_slug_1
                    [sort] => 1
                )

         [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [title] => Категория 2
                    [slug] => cat_slug_2
                    [sort] => 2
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: Нельзя обойтись одним.

Comment: `SELECT * as contacts FROM Contacts UNION ALL SELECT * as categories FROM categories` это синтаксис новый в SQL `SELECT * as contacts` ?

Comment: Множественные запросы: ¶
http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php

Comment: не знаю, я учусь, в сети как вычитал так и пишу.

Comment: Вобщем если я правильно понял, одним запросом не получится

Comment: Правильно понял. Мало того, что не получится - а вот оно нафига? геморроиться со склеиванием наборов данных на MySQL, чтобы потом геморроиться с их разделением на PHP?

Comment: @Akina Пишу свою mvc и по идее необходимо минимизировать количество запросов. Категории и контакты всегда будут на всех страницах, так почему бы не объединить в один запрос? А вдруг потом добавится ещё какая-то постоянная информация из третьей таблицы - делать уже три запроса? А так просто в модели можно изменить запрос и всё будет работать. Данные все будут передаваться в виды одним объектом и трудностей распределения не будет. Разве я не прав?

Comment: Ну... я бы сказал, что да, неправ. Ты сейчас похож на кладовщика, который складывает спецовки и сапоги в один ящик, потому как всё одно каждый рабочий получает и то, и другое... тебе уже давным-давно @2SRTVF дал совершенно правильную ссылку на мультизапрос - когда несколько несвязанных запросов отправляется на сервер одной командой, а оттуда поступает несколько несвязанных наборов данных единым потоком. Так что внимательнейшим образом изучи ссылку - это стопроцентное решение твоей хотелки. В т.ч. и на случай появления "третьей постоянной информации".